# JBoss Embedded jUnit testing for EJB : NameNotFoundException

Tags: jpa, junit, ejb, jboss7.x

I'm newbie in EJB and jUnit, and I'm trying to do Embedded testing for the simple EJB-project that running by jBoss AS 7.1.1.Final.

I've written this test:

```
package com.staff.test.logic;

import java.io.File;

import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import org.jboss.as.embedded.EmbeddedServerFactory;
import org.jboss.as.embedded.StandaloneServer;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.staff.main.logic.ProjectBean;

public class ProjectBeanTest {

    private StandaloneServer    server;
    private static EJBContainer ec;
    private static Context ctx;

    @Before
    public void initContainer() throws Exception {
    String jbossHomeDir = System.getenv("JBOSS_HOME");
    System.setProperty("jboss.home","C:/eclipse/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final");
    assert jbossHomeDir != null;
    server = EmbeddedServerFactory.create(new File(jbossHomeDir), System.getProperties(), System.getenv(), "org.jboss.logmanager");
    server.start();

    ctx=server.getContext();
    }

//    @After
//    public static void closeContainer() throws Exception {
//        if (ec != null) {
//            ec.close();
//        }
//    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws NamingException {
        ProjectBean bean = (ProjectBean) ctx.lookup("java:global/ProjectBean");
    }
}
```

But string

> ProjectBean bean = (ProjectBean) ctx.lookup("java:global/ProjectBean") make exception:

do this exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ProjectBean -- service jboss.naming.context.java.global.ProjectBean
at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBa sedNamingStore.java:97)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java: 178)
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.jav a:123)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java: 214)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at com.staff.test.logic.ProjectBeanTest.test(ProjectBeanTest.ja va:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall( FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(Refl ectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(Fr ameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate( InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(Ru nBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271 )
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit 4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit 4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java: 63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java :236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java: 53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java: 229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.r un(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(Test Execution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTe sts(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTe sts(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(R emoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main( RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I dont understand why this string do exception, because I'm newbie.

My project have a bean "ProjectBean" with interface "ProjectBeanLocal" and an entity "Post". And I have a file persistence.xml to work with Oracle 10g.

ProjectBean:

```
package com.staff.main.logic;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;

import com.staff.main.domain.Post;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class ProjectBean
 */
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ProjectBean implements ProjectBeanLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="StaffPU")
    EntityManager manager;

    public ProjectBean() 
    {  
        Ejb3Configuration cfg = new Ejb3Configuration();
        cfg.configure("StaffPU", null);
        SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(cfg.getHibernateConfiguration());
        //schemaExport.setOutputFile("schema.sql");
        schemaExport.create(true, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void savePost(Post post){
        manager.persist(post);
    }

    @Override
    public Post findPost(long id) {
        Post post=manager.find(Post.class, id);
        return post;
    }
}
```

Interface ProjectBeanLocal:

```
package com.staff.main.logic;

import javax.ejb.Local;
import com.staff.main.domain.Post;

@Local
public interface ProjectBeanLocal {
    void savePost(Post post);
    Post findPost(long id);
}
```

Entity "Post":

```
package com.staff.main.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
public class Post implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6767319776206583629L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="ent2seq",sequenceName="seq_post")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="ent2seq")
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
        version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="StaffPU">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
<!--            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.show_sql" value="true" /> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" /> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose your bean with a [Remote](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#gipiu) interface.

After that, you probably will need to change the JNDI entry name used to lookup the ejb reference.
You don't provide information about how the bean is deployed which, among other things, determines the binding name, but you can search the correct lookup string in the server log.

Comment: I've made remote interface. But I can't understand how to make JNDI.

Comment: When you make a remote JNDI invocation, you need to accomplish the following points:
1) add to client CLASSPATH the necessary dependecis, this is:add the remote interface class and the jboss-client.jar.
2) instantiate the InitialConetxt correctly (in your case this is done by the server.getContext() method which is not posted)
3) provide a correct lookup name, (this information is logged in the server when the ejb is deployed). Try to follow this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
 import org.jboss.ejb3.embedded.EJB3StandaloneBootstrap;
import org.jboss.ejb3.embedded.EJB3StandaloneDeployer;
```

in your pom you have to add :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.embedded</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>beta3.SP9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.embedded</groupId>
        <artifactId>thirdparty-all</artifactId>
        <version>beta3.SP9</version>
    </dependency>
```

you have to add :

1. embedded-jboss-beans.xml
2. bean.xml,default.persistence.properties
3. ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml
   into your resources folder and jndi.properties too whtch contains :

   java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.LocalOnlyContextFactory
    java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces

   and you test class must contains :

   EJB3StandaloneBootstrap.boot(null);
    EJB3StandaloneBootstrap.scanClasspath();
    EJB3StandaloneBootstrap.deployXmlResource(embeded.xml)
   deployer = EJB3StandaloneBootstrap.createDeployer(); 
    deployer.getArchives().add(new File("target/classes").toURI().toURL());
    deployer.create();
    deployer.start();
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();

and you look up your ejb