# Understanding of embeddable EJBContainer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, integration-testing

I spent some time in attempts to understand [Embeddable Enterprise Bean Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkcrr.html) and still need some clarifications. Assume I need `Junit` to test `EJB` application.

So I have assumptions what should happened, please help me figure out correct answer:

1. `Junit` is entrypoint and it deploys `EJB` application to server? So that EJB and Jboss are "embedded" into tests.
2. `Junit` and 'EJB' application are two separate JVM processes and they somehow communicate by jndi names or something(I don't use remote EJB).
3. Real server(JBoss) never used and `EJBContainer` is just kind of Mock.
4. Something else.

---

**Edited:**

I found an [example](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/199841):

Could you please comment on this code:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
          String jbossHomeDir = "E:\\dev_station\\java_station\\Serveurs\\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final";
          System.setProperty("jboss.home.dir", jbossHomeDir);
          StandaloneServer server = EmbeddedServerFactory.create(new File(
                              jbossHomeDir), System.getProperties(), System.getenv(),
                              "org.jboss.logmanager");
          server.start();
          server.deploy(new File("target/classes"));
          Context namingContext = server.getContext();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is exactly your aim? Is it to test EJBs? Or is it to understand how StandaloneServer works? If it is the latter, just run the example and see if another process is created, and whether there is a possibility to access the EJBs deployed etc. If it is the former, and it is about JBoss, then probably the common approach is to use Arquillian (for example http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/arquillian-ejb-jar-ear-testing).

Comment: @Jhon Donn, The aim is to understand will I have `original` server with `original` application running when I run Embedded EJB. What is the difference between original `server EJB container` and `embedded`?

Comment: About Arquillian.  If I have a ear with complicated dependencies inside will Arquillian resolve it and deploy it correctly. Again, will it be all about original server and original application or Arquillian creates stubs and mocks as well?

Comment: My "educated guess" is that the standalone server is a **real** jboss server, not a "mock" of some kind, and that it really runs the original application (perhaps this server has limited functionality?). Here is, by the way, another link I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817754/jboss-embedded-junit-testing-for-ejb-namenotfoundexception

Comment: If you wish to test just the EJB, then Arquillian would seem to me the right approach (it is designed for integration testing, so you will have the repositories etc wired, see the link in my first comment and examples on the web, e.g. https://github.com/fmarchioni/practical-javaee7-development-wildfly/tree/master/code/chapter8/javaee7-test). But I think it does not test packaging etc.

Comment: Note this example test is *not* an example of the Java EE "embedded EJB container". The `org.jboss.as.embedded.EmbeddedServerFactory` class is JBoss-specific, and has no direct relation with the standard `javax.ejb.embedded.EJBContainer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java EE 6 Tutorial (that first link in the question) says that

> The embedded container, the enterprise bean components, and the client all are executed in the same virtual machine using the same classpath.

That is, the JUnit test ("client"), the embedded container (implemented by JBoss Wildfly, Glassfish, etc.), and the Java EE application components (EJBs, etc.) all run in the same JVM instance (the same process).

Nothing is mocked. Container services (transactions, injection, etc.) are provided by an actual Java EE server implementation.

So, the correct alternative between those four listed in the question is number **1**.